# How Do I Manage Multiple Kernel Modules by the Same Name?

Tags: linux, kernel-module

I have a situation where I have two modules both named cxgb3 and both in /lib/modules/. How do I inform the OS which one to prefer?

Consider this example:

```
$ find /lib/modules/ -name cxgb3.ko
/lib/modules/2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64/extra/mlnx-ofa_kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/chelsio/cxgb3/cxgb3.ko
/lib/modules/2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/cxgb3/cxgb3.ko
```

Currently it uses the top one but I want it to use the bottom one. I am using CentOS 6.5.

Comment: Are we talking about module autoloading or simply modprobe/insmod?

Comment: Preferably autoloading, but it would be nice to determine how to do it via modprobe too. I did notice modprobe has the -t and -l options that might work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to do this is the [depmod](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/depmod.d.5.html) command. It controls the order in which modules are processed. Also, there are configuration files in /etc/depmod.d/ on my CentOS 6 box.